handle Esc key on form in a A11y friendly way
I have a form in a Svelte app like this:
  <!-- markup for editing todo: label, input text, Cancel and Save Button -->
  <form on:submit|preventDefault={onSave} class="stack-small" on:keydown={e => e.key === 'Escape' && onCancel()}>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="todo-{todo.id}" class="todo-label">New name for '{todo.name}'</label>
      <input bind:value={name} type="text" id="todo-{todo.id}" autoComplete="off" class="todo-text" />
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button class="btn todo-cancel" on:click={onCancel} type="button">
        Cancel<span class="visually-hidden">renaming {todo.name}</span>
        </button>
      <button class="btn btn__primary todo-edit" type="submit" disabled={!name}>
        Save<span class="visually-hidden">new name for {todo.name}</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>

I want to execute onCancel() when the user press the esc key on the input or in any button, but I get the following warning:

A11y: Non-interactive element <form> should not be assigned mouse or keyboard event listeners.

What would be the correct way to handle it?

It always depends on the situation. The important part is that all actions are somehow possible via keyboard and mouse and that users using screen readers get all necessary information.
Since here the cancel can also be invoked via a regular button (and the handler is not concerned with handling events dirctly dispatched to the element which would require the element to be focusable & focused), I would say that this fine.
The only thing that may be an issue is feedback on the cancel being executed. If this form is part of a dialog and this just closes the dialog, that would be the expected action on ESC. Usually then the focus should switch back to whatever opened the dialog, which should give enough context.
Especially when handling bubbling events you may get some false positive warnings. If the warning is determined to be a false positive you can ignore it via a <!-- svelte-ignore a11y-<code> --> comment above.

Keyboard events are normally not propagated to parent elements.
Therefore, non-focusable elements can never trigger any keydown/up/press event, or at least, you can never be sure that it will everywhere in all cases.
Unfortunately, you must handle the escape key individually on all focusable elements, and you must do it yourself since nothing special is done.
Here's a quick example launching the reset action upon pressing escape in any form field:
function resetOnEscape (e) {
  if (e.keyCode==27) e.target.form.reset();
}

for (let e of document.querySelectorAll('input, textarea, select, button')) {
  e.addEventListener('keydown', resetOnEscape, false);
}

In fact, for a cancel  button, you should use a button with type=reset and react to the reset event of the form.
For the same reason as the submit button shouldn't have a click event because you can submit the forum simply by pressing enter in any field instead of reaching the submit button, there may exist a shortcut for resetting the form without the need to reach the reset button.
In reality, such a shortcut doesn't exist yet anywhere as far as I know, sadly, but it could well be the escape key.
